# How to configure camel casing serializing settings globally in Flurl Http?

Tags: .net-core, flurl

I wanted to have a camel case serialized json while using PostAsync in Flurl

Answer (score 2):

```
FlurlHttp.Configure(settings =>
{
    var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    };
    settings.JsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(jsonSettings);
});
```